# Returning an error with the value instead only the needed value │ Scheme

Tags: list, function, variables, scheme, racket

**First of all, thanks for reading.**

Well, the problem i have; i did some functions for an exercise that i need to solve.

The purpose is: get two rectangles (created by 2 points in a plane X,Y each one) and see the smaller diference between those.

i did this code:

```
(define-struct coord (x y))
(define-struct rt (cd1 cd2))

; instances (points)

(define c1 (make-coord 10 20))
(define c2 (make-coord 20 30))
(define c3 (make-coord 1 2))
(define c4 (make-coord 5 10))

;; Rectangles

(define rect1 (make-rt c1 c2))
(define rect2 (make-rt c3 c4))

;; Functions : 

(define (small list)
    (cond
      [(null? (cdr list)) (car list)]
      [(< (car list) (small (cdr list))) (car list)]
      [else (small (cdr list))])) ;; Function for extract the small number in a list

(define (distance2rt pt1x pt2x pt1y pt2y) (sqrt ( + (expt ( - pt2x pt1x ) 2) (expt ( - pt2y pt1y ) 2) ) )) ; The operation

(define (extcrd rt num letter) (cond
                        [(and (equal? num 1) (equal? letter "x")) (coord-x(rt-cd1 rt))]
                        [(and (equal? num 2) (equal? letter "x")) (coord-x(rt-cd2 rt))]
                        [(and (equal? num 1) (equal? letter "y")) (coord-y(rt-cd1 rt))]
                        [(and (equal? num 2) (equal? letter "y")) (coord-y(rt-cd2 rt))]
                        )) ;; Another function :)

(define (distanceop r1 r2) (small(
                              (distance2rt (extcrd r1 1 "x") (extcrd r2 1 "x") (extcrd r1 2 "y") (extcrd r2 2 "y"))
                              (distance2rt (extcrd r1 1 "x") (extcrd r2 1 "x") (extcrd r1 1 "y") (extcrd r2 1 "y"))
                              (distance2rt (extcrd r1 2 "x") (extcrd r2 2 "x") (extcrd r1 2 "y") (extcrd r2 2 "y"))
                              (distance2rt (extcrd r1 2 "x") (extcrd r2 2 "x") (extcrd r1 1 "y") (extcrd r2 1 "y"))
                              ))
  ) ;; The main function combining operation and the list

(distanceop rect1 rect2)
```

if i run this it throw me this error:

```
function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received #i21.93171219946131
```

***#i21.93171219946131*** is the number i need, and is correct (after all the operations).

i don't know what i need to do.

**Thanks again.**

Comment: Hint: `small` wants a *list* of values.

Comment: @molbdnilo Really thanks! i did a list with the distance operations and the "small" function and it works. THANKS!!